# Numpy getting exact shape

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy (1.9.2) matrix which returns when I do a A.shape(6L,3L).
However, I am not able to create an array with that shape.

I have tried,

```
Z=np.ones((6,3))
Z.shape return (6,3) # does not return (6L,3L)
```

I also tried

```
Z=Z.reshape(6L,3L)
Z.shape # still return (6,3)
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: `L` means only `long integer` and `6 == 6L`

Comment: Can you explain what your goal is?

Comment: Long and int was unified a while back. AFAIK on typical python installs there is no difference see the PEP [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0237/).

Answer (score 1):

`ndarray.shape` just returns a tuple, so you can use that to create an array if you wish:

```
np.zeros(np.ones((6, 3)).shape)
```

or even

```
np.zeros_like(np.ones((6, 3)))
```

Answer (score -1):

No you're not missing anything.  Numpy doesn't even try to so large an array that a Python long integer must be used to count its size.

```
>>> import sys
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.empty(sys.maxint + 1)
ValueError: Maximum allowed dimension exceeded
```

Explanation:

Numpy array dimensions are stored internally using a C type `npy_intp` (exported in Python as `numpy.intp`).  This is simply an alias to platform's `ssize_t`.

The `ssize_t` type, on the other hand, in practice means 64-bit integer (same as pointer width) on 64-bit systems.  I talk about 64-bit only because that's what practicality (and your problem seems to have) implied.

When you try to get an array's size in Python, numpy must convert this into a value in a Python integral type.  Normally[1], Python's "bare" (i.e. not long) integer should be just enough to hold this value.  This is because in Python (at least 2.x) implementation, the "bare" integer is an integer with value bound by the platform's `LONG_MAX`, as defined in the header `limits.h`.  On practically all platforms[1], such an integer can just be held in a pointer-wide variable, so everything coincides -- `npy_intp`, Python "bare" integer, and C `LONG_MAX`-bound integer.

It further means that when you try to create a numpy array with one of the dimensions larger than can be accommodated by a Python "bare" integer, this would have overflown `npy_intp` so Numpy will simply raise an exception without actually trying to do anything.

[1] However, there can be exceptions.  I'm only aware of MS Windows (64-bit) could be an exception.  On such platform, the largest Python "bare" integer, bound by that platform's `LONG_MAX`, is actually just 32-bit.  In this case, `npy_intp` can be larger than Python "bare" integer, so when you read a numpy array's size, you could get a Python long integer (that would otherwise have been "bare" on another platform).
But I haven't used Windows for practically anything for a decade, so I may be wrong, and feel free to correct me.

Comment: This is not true, `sys.maxint` effectively returns C++'s `size_t`. `np.empty(2**32+1)` works just fine on a 64bit machine with sufficient memory.

Comment: On a 64-bit machine, `sys.maxint` should be equal to `(1 << 63) - 1`

Comment: Yes, that is effectively what I said. You are missing the point that a long int must be used to define the length of an array with `2**32 + 1` elements.

Comment: `sys.maxint` returns the platform's `LONG_MAX` as defined by `limits.h`. Numpy's `npy_intp` is used internally for all indexing, and it's an alias to C `ssize_t`. Usually, but not exactly always, the limit of `ssize_t`, `SSIZE_MAX`, coincides with `LONG_MAX`, which should be (2^63 - 1) on 64bit machines (but could be smaller, as long as it's larger than (2^31 - 1)).  The point is that a "real" Python long integer is hardly convertible to numpy's `npy_intp` if ever, so you never get from an array a size large enough to guarantee a Python long integer representing it.